# Como exibir as imagem salva no banco?

Tags: php, mysqli

Não consigo exibir as fotos que estou mandando para o banco de dados. Estou fazendo um *e-commerce* com foto e consegui mandá-las para o banco de dados (*MySQL*). Criei meu banco, depois minha tabela. Fiz a conexão e todos os itens da tabela estão recebendo seus dados, só que a foto não é exibida quando a chamo. Na pagina *home*, consigo chamar todos os dados, mas a foto não aparece, só seu nome.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Cadastrar:**

```
<?php
        include_once("conexao.php");
        $arquivo    = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];

        //Pasta onde o arquivo vai ser salvo
        $_UP['pasta'] = 'foto/';

        //Tamanho máximo do arquivo em Bytes
        $_UP['tamanho'] = 1024*1024*100; //5mb

        //Array com a extensões permitidas
        $_UP['extensoes'] = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif');

        //Renomeiar
        $_UP['renomeia'] = false;

        //Array com os tipos de erros de upload do PHP
        $_UP['erros'][0] = 'Não houve erro';
        $_UP['erros'][1] = 'O arquivo no upload é maior que o limite do PHP';
        $_UP['erros'][2] = 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho especificado no HTML';
        $_UP['erros'][3] = 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente';
        $_UP['erros'][4] = 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo';

        //Verifica se houve algum erro com o upload. Sem sim, exibe a mensagem do erro
        if($_FILES['arquivo']['error'] != 0){
            die("Não foi possivel fazer o upload, erro: <br />". $_UP['erros'][$_FILES['arquivo']['error']]);
            exit; //Para a execução do script
        }


        //Faz a verificação do tamanho do arquivo
        else if ($_UP['tamanho'] < $_FILES['arquivo']['size']){
            echo "
                <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/Gui/upload_imagem.php'>
                <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"Arquivo muito grande.\");
                </script>
            ";
        }

        //O arquivo passou em todas as verificações, hora de tentar move-lo para a pasta foto
        else{
            //Primeiro verifica se deve trocar o nome do arquivo
            if($UP['renomeia'] == true){
                //Cria um nome baseado no UNIX TIMESTAMP atual e com extensão .jpg
                $nome_final = time().'.jpg';
            }else{
                //mantem o nome original do arquivo
                $nome_final = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
            }
            //Verificar se é possivel mover o arquivo para a pasta escolhida
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta']. $nome_final)){
                //Upload efetuado com sucesso, exibe a mensagem
                $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO produtos (
                nome_imagem) VALUES('$nome_final')");
                echo "
                    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/Gui/fotos'>
                    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert(\"Imagem cadastrada com Sucesso.\");
                    </script>
                ";  
            }else{
                //Upload não efetuado com sucesso, exibe a mensagem
                echo "
                    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/Gui/fotos'>
                    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert(\"Imagem não foi cadastrada com Sucesso.\");
                    </script>
                ";
            }
        }


    ?>
```

**Onde as imagens deveriam aparecer:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['pesquisar'])){


    //reutiliza o codigo
    include_once ('conexao.php');


    $nome = $_POST['nome_imagem'];




    $sql ="SELECT * FROM produtos where nome_imagem like '%$nome%'";


    echo '<table class="table table-bordered">';
        echo '<thead>';
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<th>Produtos</th>';
            echo '</tr>';
        echo '</thead>';
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['nome_imagem'].'</td>' . '<td>'. '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Inserir</button>' . '</td>' . '<td>'. '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">editar</button>'.'</td>'. '<td>' . '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">excluir</button>' . '</td>' ;
        echo '</tr>';
        }       
        echo '</table>';    
        }   

?>
```

Comment: Por gentileza edite seu código.
Sua imagem está num blob do banco de dados? Se sim é necessário criar um handler para enviar a foto ao cliente. É possível fazer isso também com base64, mas esse método consome mais banda e processamento.

Comment: Pelo código  que ela postou, não, ela salvou o nome do arquivo na tabela, e recupera esse nome dentro do filesistem do webserver na hora de exacutar, se esse diretório estiver dentro do escopo do fileserver é só ela incluir a TAG IMG

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<img src="'.$row['nome_imagem'].'">';
```

ou caso precise defina o caminho completo da imagem

```
echo '<img src="./path/'.$row['nome_imagem'].'">';
```

ou ainda o caminho absoluto

```
echo '<img src="https://servidorx.com/path/'.$row['nome_imagem'].'">';
```

Basta usar esta TAG HTML IMG, usando ECHO, você esta simplesmente imprimindo (ecoando) o conteúdo do campo literalmente, ou seja mostrando o nome do arquivo, mais não usando o HTML para mostrar a imagem. Qualquer dúvida manda mais detalhado onde esta salvando a imagem, e se ela está dentro de um local no servidor que possa ser lido pelo webserver, caso não seja, você tem outras alternativas.